# Why is the count of events marked as a conversion not increasing in the conversion tab

Tags: firebase-analytics

Im using Firebase Analytics with custom events. Some events are marked as conversion, and those events have appeared in the conversion tab, but they don't fire, their count is always 0.

[Screenshot from the events tab, you can see the event, is firing, and it is marked as a conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RsnO.png)
[Screenshot from the conversion tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLzON.png)

Can anybody explain why it happens, maybe I set up something wrong.

I'm expecting to see a count of marked as conversion events more than zero.